# How to remove ParseInt NaN issues from the code?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

This is my code i'm trying to get the sum from input values . 
It works fine when i enter numbers but as soon as i clear any input field i get total as NaN. i know using parseInt for number value is troubling , but if i'm not using parseInt it appends number instead of  getting doing Sum on input Values .
I want to solve it ? why NaN is coming and how to make this code error free .. don't want to use if else for NaN or IsNan please suggest practical approach --

```
<template>
<div>
<form @submit.prevent="submit" autocomplete="off">


    <div class="form-group d-flex mt-3">

        <label for="zero" class="p-2 bg-info text-white redius-5">0</label>
    <input style="width:100px;" min="0" class="form-control" name="zero" id="zero" v-model.number="zero" @click="doSum" v-model="fields.zero" oninput="validity.valid||(value=''); " />
    <div v-if="errors && errors.zero" class="text-danger">{{ errors
        .zero[0] }}</div>
        <label for="one" class="p-2 bg-info text-white">1</label>
        <input style="width:100px;" min="0" type="number" class="form-control" name="one" v-model.number="one" id="one" @click="doSum" v-model="fields.one"  oninput="validity.valid||(value=''); "/>
        <div v-if="errors && errors.one" class="text-danger">{{ errors.one[0] }}</div>
        <label for="two" class="p-2 bg-info text-white">2</label>
        <input style="width:100px;" min="0" type="number" class="form-control" name="two" v-model.number="two" id="two" @click="doSum" v-model="fields.two" oninput="validity.valid||(value=''); " />
        <div v-if="errors && errors.two" class="text-danger">{{ errors.two[0] }}</div>
</div>


            Total = {{ Bettotal }}

</form>
</div>
```

```
<script>

export default {
    props: ['game_id', 'userId', 'this.rows'],

    mounted() {
        console.log('Component mounted.')
    },

    data() {
        return {
            timestamp: 0,
            selectedGame: {},
            gamesinfo: [],
            zero:0,
            one:0,
            two:0,
            Bettotal:0,
            gamex: this.gameId,
            rows: [],
            count: 0,
            fields: {},
            errors: {},
            success: false,
            loaded: true,
        };
    },

doSum: function () {
  this.Bettotal = parseInt(this.zero) + parseInt(this.one) + parseInt(this.two);
   // if (isNaN(this.Bettotal)) this.Bettotal = 0;
    return this.Bettotal;
},
};
```

Comment: Instead of acc+=parseInt(row.value)  try acc+=(row.value -0). I think that simple hack should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i have added a validator and now its not giving me NaN

```
oninput="this.value = Math.abs(this.value);
```

Answer (score 3):

In your total() method instead of

`acc += parseInt(row.value)`

try:

```
acc += (row.value - 0)
```

I think that simple hack should work because it will convert it to number when you subtract zero from empty string.